# Space of Continuous mappings to metric spaces

Tags: functional-analysis, continuity, banach-spaces, normed-spaces

I want to ask whether some basic result from the space $C([0,1],R)$, where $R$ is the real space carries over to the space $C([0,1],E)$, where $(E,\|\cdot\|_E)$ is a metric space.

We know that $C([0,1],R)$ equipped with the supremum norm is a Polish space. I want to ask whether the same can be said of the space $C([0,1],E)$ equipped with similar supremum norm $\sup_{t\in[0,1]}\|\cdot\|_E$. Has there been any result on whether the same is also true this more general space by maybe assuming that $E$ is Polish as well? Or are there some counterexamples? Thank you.

Solutions:

Regarding separability: What if we assume that $(E,<\cdot,\cdot>_E)$ is a separable Hilbert space and use Parseval's equality?

Regarding completeness: Assume $E$ is Banach.

Then I think $C([0,1],E)$ is also complete. Let's denote the supremum norm in $C([0,1],E)$ by $\|\cdot\|_\infty$. Suppose $(x_n)\subseteq C([0,1],E)$ is a Cauchy sequence. Then for any $n\in\mathbb{N}$, $\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\epsilon_n:=\sup_{m\geq n}\|x_n-x_m\|_\infty=0$. Furthermore, for any $t\in[0,1]$, $(x_n(t))\subseteq E$ is then also Cauchy, and hence has a limit $x(t)$. We can show that $x$ is indeed the limit of $(x_n)$. For every $t\in[0,1]$ it holds that

\begin{equation}
\begin{split}
\|x_n(t)-x_m(t)\|_E\leq\epsilon_n
\end{split}
\end{equation}

and this implies that

\begin{equation}
\begin{split}
\lim_{m\rightarrow\infty}\|x_n(t)-x_m(t)\|_E=\|x_n(t)-x(t)\|_E\leq\epsilon_n.
\end{split}
\end{equation}

Since $t\in[0,1]$ was arbitrarily chosen, it holds that

\begin{equation}
\begin{split}
\|x_n-x\|_\infty\leq\epsilon_n.
\end{split}
\end{equation}

Upon taking $n\rightarrow\infty$, we see that $x_n$ converges uniformly to $x$. This also easily shows that $x\in C([0,1],E)$.

Comment: is $C([0,T],E)$ complete?